# Change Windows 7 folder background color because it is not complete white

Tags: windows-7

I noticed it is not complete white.

I checked in paint, shows [252, 252, 252]. It's not complete white.

I can't test Windows 7 because my other PC use Windows 8.1. I checked 8.1 use complete white folder background [255, 255, 255].

Is it normal for Windows 7 has non-white color for folder background?

How can I change it to complete white?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to find a way to change that to a dark colour.

Comment: It looks like they figured it out in this thread: http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/60544-how-change-windows-folder-bg-2.html